# Dropdown autopostback problem with browsers back button

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, autopostback, selectedindexchanged, back-button

I have 3 dropdownlist

First dropdownlist is pulling categories when i select a category from ddlist 1, 
I fill second dropdownlist with sub categories of a category which i selected on ddlist1.

When i selected a sub category from ddlist2 i fill the third ddlist with products.

When i select a product from ddlist3 its redirecting me the products detail page.

If i press back button of the browser and select another category from ddlist1, ddlist1's selectedindexchange event firing after this event worked something is triggering ddlist3's selectedindexchange event even i dont touch ddlist3.

Note : I am clearing items in the ddlist2 and ddlist3 on ddlist1's selectedIndexChange event.

Answer (score 0):

When you clear the items, does the `ddlist3` index reset to 0? This change can fire the `SelectedIndexChange` event.

Comment: It can be but im clearing ddlist2 first it should fire ddlist2's event first but its firing ddlist3's SelectedIndexChange event firstly.